# Solr version compatiblity with Sitecore 9

Tags: solr

My team is planning to install Sitecore 9. We are using Solr 5.5 version at the moment. Can we use this Solr version?  Is this Solr version compatible with sitecore 9 and if we can work with this?

Answer (score 5):

By official documentation, Solr 6.6.1 is compatible with Sitecore 9. This version of Solr 6.6.1 is officially tested and recommended.

[image]
You refer to office release notes https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897.

Comment: Just with one caveat. Solr 6.6.1 has a bug that can stop the installation working. V6.6.2 has a fix for that, so use that version.

Comment: Supporting @RichardSeal comment.  I would use 6.6.2.

Comment: agree with Richard.

Answer (score 2):

The Sitecore 9 initial release had bugs, so the patch version was introduced.
Now the latest version is **Sitecore 9 update-1**.

Sitecore compatibility table shows all compatibility of Sitecore CMS and Sitecore XP with different browsers, operating systems, .NET frameworks, and database servers.

[Sitecore Compatibility Table](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164)
and the [Solr Compatibility](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897) latest recommended version is **Solr 6.6.2**

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897